# javascript loop through array with "for" and "ForEach"

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i'm trying to create a function that take an array as an argument, and return "true" only if all the items inside the array are the same .
i try to use **for loop** and i try to use **forEeach loop**

the first one work great.
 the second one not!.
**why?**
this my first code:

```
function isUniform(ary) {
    var first = ary[0];
    for (i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (first !== ary[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
        return true;
}
console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 1]));
```

this my second one:

```
function isUniform(ary) {
    var first = ary[0];
    ary.forEach(function(element) {
        if (first !== element) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
 console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: How about logging the values in the forEach loop and checking what they are?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell that's irrelevant ... the issue is there is nowhere to return to in `forEach` and return of an inner closure doesn't return to the outer one

Answer (score 7):

The "inner" `return` in your second example is a return from the function passed to `forEach`. It does *not* cause an immediate return from the `isUniform` function. Instead, this little anonymous function you passed to `forEach` runs happily to completion for every single element of your array.

After it finishes running through all of the elements, your `isUniform` function then simply returns true.

Answer (score 1):

By returning true you are returning true to the forEach function callback while you're for loop returns true to the function.  Your forEach requires a reference object when executing a callback if you want to use your current approach. That is how it is different from your for loop.

```js
function isUniform(ary) {
  var first = ary[0];
  val = true;
  ary.forEach(element => {
    if (first !== element) {
      val = false;
    }
  });
  return val;
}
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1]));

console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 1]));
```

There is already an every function you can take advantage of.

```js
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

arr2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

console.log(arr1.every((a, _, aa) => aa[0] === a));
console.log(arr2.every((a, _, aa) => aa[0] === a));
```

Comment: While true this doesn't answer the question. Why is forEach different?

Comment: With that ```val``` you should really stick to the lexical closure, just as you do with ```first```. Bringing ```this``` into the picture pollutes the context and also makes the code confusing to read.

Comment: @Amy because of design/definition. ```forEach``` is not a conditional construct, and it does not care/check/forward/store/accumulate/etc. whatever the called function returns. If one really wants to break from a ```forEach``` loop, throwing an exception can do that, but it is not a nice solution.

Comment: Actually Amy wasn't really asking a question here, but rather pointing out, via a rhetorical device, that the answer here simply gave a forEach-based solution to a piece of code while the OP specifically asked "WHY does the forEach code fail while the for-loop code succeeds?" Cheers.

Comment: @tevemadar I know this.  I was prompting him to actually answer the question.

Comment: @RayToal was that rhetorical device simile, metaphor, metonymy, synecdoche or personification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break from a forEach.

Try this one. You can do it with the flag.

var falg = false;

function isUniform(ary) {

```
var first = ary[0];

ary.forEach(function(element) {

    if (first !== element) {

        falg = true;

        return false;

    }

});

if(falg)

    return false

return true;
```

}

console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 1]));

Answer (score 0):

The how part has been addressed in @Arrow's post already, if you work with `forEach`, it does not care about the return values, you have to accumulate the result yourself (also, there is no 'normal' way of breaking out from the loop, though you could throw an exception if you really want to).

For the 'why' part: because of definition. `forEach` does not care about return values and runs the passed function for all elements, unconditionally.

A simplified implementation of `forEach` is the following:

```
Array.prototype.myForEach=function(callback){ // or callback,diz
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;t++)
    callback(this[i],i,this);                 // or callback.call(diz,this[i],i,this);
}
```

The result of `callback` is completely ignored. (Commented parts add support for the optional context-argument)

A 'more official' polyfill does some extra checks, but it is not complicated either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

Answer (score -1):

can you try this, change the var element for x, and use lambdas

```
    function isUniform(ary) {
     var first = ary[0];
     ary.forEach((x) => {
         if(first !== x){
             return false;
         }
     });
     return true;
    }
```